# Have incremented value in v-for attr

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, attr, nuxt.js

I tried to have an incremented value with :

```
:data-value="Math.round(elecs[index].obtenus/elecs[index].maxsiege*100)
```

My iteration :

```
:data-value="Math.round(result += elecs[index].obtenus/elecs[index].maxsiege*100)
```

thanks !

More :

```
<ul class="pie-wrapper" >
          <li v-for="(elec, index)  in elecs" :key="index" v-if="elecs[index].obtenus != 0" class="arc" :data-value="Math.round(elecs[index].obtenus/elecs[index].maxsiege*100)">
            <b>{{ elecs[index].Sigle }} </b>
            <span>{{elecs[index].obtenus}}/{{elecs[index].maxsiege}}</span>
          </li>
      </ul>
```

script :

```
 export default {
async asyncData({ params }) {
  ... json
  return {
    ...json
  }
},
methods: {
  toCurrencyString(number){
    return number.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
  }
}
```

}

Comment: why do you not use computed properties for this? Can you provide a bit more code for your question?

Comment: Yes, add to my question. thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Well I found!** Thanks to Max Sinev for having me here on the right track !

```
methods: {
  toCurrencyString(number){
    return number.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
  },
  tottest(elecs, index){
    return result += Math.round(elecs[index].obtenus/elecs[index].maxsiege*100);
  }
}
```

**And in my template :**

```
      <ul class="pie-wrapper" >
          <li v-for="(elec, index)  in elecs" :key="index" v-if="elecs[index].obtenus != 0" class="arc" :data-value="tottest(elecs, index)">
          </li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: Is `result` a global variable ?

Comment: yep, just defined in my script  `var result = 0;` Someone can close that question ? i can't.